# What is a disposed object in C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, objectdisposedexception

I'm getting an ObjectDisposedException using C#:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

Before I get to why I'm getting the error, I'd like to know, what is a disposed object, exactly?

Then, after understanding that, why would this **ObjectDisposedException** occur, in general? I have a program which uploads files to and downloads files from Amazon S3, and it's giving me this error on very sporadic occasions.

Comment: Can we see your work as well?

Comment: Answer to your 2nd question: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: An `ObjectDisposedException` occurs when you access an object that has been disposed. For streams and SQL connection objects, this means that you either used the object in a "using" statement, or you explicitly called `Dispose` or `Close` on the object and tried using it again. Without seeing your code, or where this error occurs, its difficult to say why you are getting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A disposed object is an object that implements IDisposable that has had the Dispose method called. This could be called explicitly or after a using statement completes. If it's happening sporadically, it might be a race condition.

Comment: I did have an explicit Dispose method called, and the error was happening sporadically. In some code examples that were provided for the method I was using, they showed the Dispose method after a PutObject method (an Amazon SDK method), and some did not. For now I took out the Dispose method, and so far seems ok, I'll have to monitor. Thanks for suggestions and explanation.

Comment: As a general rule, you're supposed to call Dispose on an object if it implements IDisposable, but don't call it before you're done with the object. If you're going to have one object available to upload and download files for the entire time the program is running, just dispose it when the program closes (ideally in a finally block).